# How do I programmatically determine if an object is a 'linked duplicate' of another?

Tags: python, scripting, linked-data

I'm trying to determine if an object is a linked duplicate in a script.

My test scene is as simple as possible, 2 cubes, one a linked duplicate of another.

The following I have tried to no avail:

- `bpy.data.objects["Cube.001"].library (returns None)`
- `bpy.data.objects["Cube.001"].original (returns "Cube.001")`
- `bpy.data.objects["Cube.001"].is_property_set("linked")` (fails to run)

I attempted to grep around in the source code to find a solution but I, unfortunately, couldn't find anything that worked.

Comment: `bpy.objects["Foo"].data`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Object.data`**

Linked duplicates will have the same linked data, if there is linked data.  For an empty `ob.data is None`

```
import bpy
from collections import defaultdict

scene = bpy.context.scene

data_links = defaultdict(list)
for ob in scene.objects:
    data_links[ob.data].append(ob)
    
for k, v in data_links.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Sample output,  notice there are 4 objects using the mesh "Cube.001"

```
<bpy_struct, Mesh("Cube.001")> [bpy.data.objects['Cube'], bpy.data.objects['Cube.001'], bpy.data.objects['Cube.002'], bpy.data.objects['Cube.003']]
<bpy_struct, PointLight("Lamp")> [bpy.data.objects['Lamp']]
<bpy_struct, Camera("Camera")> [bpy.data.objects['Camera']]
None [bpy.data.objects['Empty'], bpy.data.objects['Field']]
```

Comment: My first brush with `defaultdict`. Python is _very_ neat and tidy, sometimes.. :)